# Call functions in a class using a function in another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on some work and I keep on getting into a problem. I tried about an hour to solve this but I cannot figure it out.
Here is a simplified version of my problem;

```
import random
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(class1,self).__init__()
        self.createX()
    def createX(self):
        self.x = random.randint(1,20)

class class2(class1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(class2,self).__init__()
        self.n = 4
    def create(self):
        self. n = self.n + self.x

class main(object):
    def __init__(self,c,c2):
        self.x = c
        self.n = c2

        self.x = self.x.x
        self.n = self.n.n

        self.print()
        self.createnew()
        self.print()
    def print(self):
        print('x=',self.x)
        print('n',self.n)

    def createnew(self):
        c = class1()
        c2 = class2()
        c2.create()


c = class1()
c2 = class2()
c2.create()

m = main(c,c2)
```

I have made 3 classes. Class1 just creates a variable called self.x using the random function.
Next class2 creates another variable called self.n. These two classes interlink using inheritance, up to this point everything works fine. Then I have my main class that takes all the variables from the other classes and uses it within its own class. It has two functions; One that prints and the other that calls the classes again. 
When I run the program this is printed:

```
x= 7
n 7
x= 7
n 7
```

I don't understand why the second time round x and n do not change values even though I called the classes that they are created in, using the 'createnew' function in my main class.

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please don't name your function `print`! This is bound to cause trouble on the way...

Answer (score 5):

`createnew()` has no significance. It creates new local variables and throw them away.

```
def createnew(self):
    c = class1()
    c2 = class2()
    self.c2.create()
```

`c` and `c2` are only local to `createnew`. They have nothing to do with and do not change `c` and `c2` that were used to create the instance of the `main` class.

You should keep a reference to the "original" `c` and `c2`:

```
class main(object):
    def __init__(self,c,c2):
        self.c = c
        self.c2 = c2

        self.x = self.c.x
        self.n = self.c2.n

    def createnew(self):
        self.c = class1()
        self.c2 = class2()
        self.c2.create()
        self.x = self.c.x
        self.n = self.c2.n
```

You can get away without keeping `c` and `c2` and only update `self.x` and `self.n` but that would be a bit weird:

```
class main(object):
    def __init__(self, c, c2):
        self.x = c
        self.n = c2

        self.x = self.x.x
        self.n = self.n.n

    def createnew(self):
        c = class1()
        c2 = class2()
        c2.create()
        self.x = c.x
        self.n = c2.n
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a great answer, explaining why this doesn't work.
I've been through the same problem and have found a way that will always work and link different classes:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.m = main
        self.x = 5

class Class2:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.m = main
        self.n = 4
        self.xn = self.m.cl1.x * self.n # this is the actual interlink between classes via MainClass
        return self.xn

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cl1 = Class1(self)
        self.cl2 = Class2(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MainClass()
    m.cl1()
    print(m.cl2())
```

For this you need a MainClass that holds the connection to all other classes. It creates references to Class1 and Class2, passing itself as an argument to these classes.